# How to access to nested action in vuex store modules?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

After creating a project with [ApiPlatform](https://api-platform.com/) and generate some code with the [VueJs code generator](https://api-platform.com/docs/client-generator/vuejs) I was unable to dispatch some actions... Here is the example:

> main store file

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        ...
        producto,
        ...
    }
})
```

> main producto store file

```
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  modules: {
    list, //here is the action I want to use
    create,
    update,
    show,
    del
  }
}
```

> main producto/list store file

```
import * as actions from './actions'
import * as getters from './getters'
import mutations from './mutations'
export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state: {
    error: '',
    isLoading: false,
    items: [],
    view: []
  },
  actions,
  getters,
  mutations
}
```

> actions file

```
const getItems = ({ commit }, page = '/productos') => {
  commit(types.TOGGLE_LOADING)

  fetch(page)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      commit(types.TOGGLE_LOADING)
      commit(types.SET_ITEMS, data['hydra:member'])
      commit(types.SET_VIEW, data['hydra:view'])
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      commit(types.TOGGLE_LOADING)
      commit(types.SET_ERROR, e.message)
    })
}

export default getItems
```

In a component I map the getter for items from producto store and I get an empty array(as expected). but when I call `this.$store.dispatch('producto/list/getItems')` vuex throws an error because there is no such getItems action.

I do not know why the getter is working but the action is not.

Any tip? I need to call that action in order to fill the items array from the producto store.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you import `getItems` into `producto/list` file?

Comment: Is the actions entry... updated

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need `namespaced: true` on the main store as well as the producto store

```js
export default new Vuex.Store({
  namespaced: true,
  modules: {
    ...
    producto,
    ...
  }
})
```

because `this.$store.dispatch('producto/list/getItems')` effectively has two namespaces in it.